# Can linear frame dragging cause gravitational dipole radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory, frame-dragging

I have just learned that linear frame dragging exists in General Relativity. I have also seen simulations where a periodically accelerated and decelerated mass causes a sort of gravitational dipole radiation, dragging nearby masses in the direction of the acceleration.
My problem with this is that in my whole life I was taught that the leading order in gravitational radiation is quadrupole; dipole radiation can't exist because of conservation of linear and angular momentum.
Is dipole radiation forbidden only in linearized General Relativity? What is the full picture here / what am I missing?